# In the Symfony2 documentation you can embed a collection of forms to add object, but how do you select from existing objects to add to the collection?

Tags: forms, symfony, datatables, entity

Not sure that was the clearest way of asking my question, but basically I want to try and achieve the below in Symfony2:

[image]

It is important to note that I have tried the embed a collection as per the documentation, but I am not looking to create a new object and add to the collection I am trying to select an existing object to add to the collection.

I currently have a product group entity that simply consists of an ID, Name and collection of products:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Product Group
 * @ORM\Table(name="productGroups")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class ProductGroup
{  
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="productGroups")
     **/
    protected $products;

    ...
```

I then have the product entity:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Product
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Product
{  
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=20)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ProductGroup", mappedBy="products")
     **/
    protected $productGroups;

    ...
```

What I am trying to do is create a form that allows me to create and update a product group.

I want to enter a name for the product group and then select products by ticking a check box against the rows of a table. The idea being that I could use something like datatables to filter the products to make it easier to add.

To start this off I have added a Product Group Type:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ProductGroupType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('products', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new ProductType()
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\ProductGroup',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'product_group';
    }
}
```

I then have the Product Type:

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('code');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Product',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'product';
    }
}
```

Now I am very confused about how I can have a table of products that have a checkbox that once selected and the form saved are saved against the product group.

Can anyone help or suggest any other way of doing this?

I have attached an image of what I am trying to achieve if that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the entity form type:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

```
$builder->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('code', 'text')
        ->add(
            'ProductGroups', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'YourBundle:ProductGroups',
            'label' => 'Select ProductTypes',
            'placeholder' => 'Select ProductGroups',
            'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true
            ))
            ->getForm();
    }
```

The Multiple tag will generate a list of checkboxes that allows you to select multiple productGroups